# How to adjust spacing above table of content in memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, vertical-spacing

In this simple memoir table of contents, there appears to be spacing between the heading and the table of contents. That is, the vertical space between the "Contents" rule and "1 Lorem" on the left-hand page is larger than the space between the "Lorem" rule and "Lorem ipsum ..." on the right-hand page.

How can I adjust this spacing?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\headstyles{bringhurst}
\begin{document}
(intentionally left blank)
\newpage
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Num dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{\par\nobreak\bigskip}` and `\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{10pt}` ?

Comment: @JeT: actually, the style `bringhurst` defines `\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip\onelineskip}`. And OP wants to keep the `hrule`. (So maybe: `\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\vskip\onelineskip \hrule}` ?)

Comment: Before you adjust it... Not doubt this depends on your usage, but AFAIK it is traditional to place the `Contents` title so that it is not at the topmost line. Apparently that is what `memoir` does by default.

Comment: @rallg Thank you, I hadn't heard of that. Do you know of any reference? I've checked a couple books, including Bringhurst's, and they all have the contents starting on the top line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memoir` class adds vertical space `\cftbeforechapterskip` ahead of every chapter title in the table of contents.

You can remove it ahead of the first chapter title.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\headstyles{bringhurst}
\begin{document}

(intentionally left blank)
\newpage

\tableofcontents*

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-\cftbeforechapterskip}}

\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Num dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Num dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `\aftertoctitle`, whose standard definition is `\afterchaptertitle`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\headstyles{bringhurst}

\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{%
  \afterchaptertitle % standard behavior
  \vspace{-\cftbeforechapterskip}% remove the excess
}

\begin{document}

(intentionally left blank)
\newpage

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Num dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Num dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 as always simpler than mine

Answer (score 2):

Generally `bringhurst` disables the usage of the `\afterchaptertitle` skip, which leaves the responsibility to `memoir`'s version of `\@starttoc` and `\newlistof` respectively. Following that we can conclude that the first "thing" that is happening after the chapter title in the table of contents is a `\contentsline` via the according `\@input`. Remember that `\contentsline` is defined in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\gdef\@contentsline@destination{#4}%
                          \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}}
```

So, it comes down to `\l@<#1>`; in your case `\l@chapter`, which in `memoir` looks like:

```
\newcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{#1}{#2}{\cftchaptername}}
```

Another level of abstraction down and we find that:

```
\newcommand*{\l@chapapp}[3]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \cftchapterbreak
    \vskip \cftbeforechapterskip
    {%\leftskip \cftchapterindent\relax
     \memRTLleftskip \cftchapterindent\relax
%%%     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \memRTLrightskip \@tocrmarg
%%%     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parfillskip -\memRTLrightskip
     \parindent \cftchapterindent\relax
     \@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftchapterpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftchapteraftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftchapteraftersnumb
     \def\@chapapp@head{#3}%
     \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cftchapterfont\@chapapp@head}%
     \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftchapternumwidth}%
%%%     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     \advance\memRTLleftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\memRTLleftskip
     {\cftchapterfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftchapterfillnum{#2}}
  \fi}
```

Finally it is the dimension `\cftbeforechapterskip` that "pollutes" the spacing. A very simple thing, hence, you could try is

```
\makeatletter
\setlength\cftbeforechapterskip{\z@}
\makeatother
```

Maybe more elegant and less crude would be the use of the `xpatch` package:

```
\def\m@patch@toc@padding@top{%
  \def\m@patch@toc@padding@top{\vskip \cftbeforechapterskip}
}
\patchcmd\l@chapapp{%
  \vskip \cftbeforechapterskip% search
}{%
  \m@patch@toc@padding@top% replace
}{}{}% success / failure
```

If you want to control the spacing afterwards you could add something like

```
\renewcommand*\afterchaptertitle{%
  \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip \afterchapskip
}
\setlength\afterchapskip{12\p@} % add your desired spacing here
```

### Entire Code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\headstyles{bringhurst}

\makeatletter
\def\m@patch@toc@padding@top{%
  \def\m@patch@toc@padding@top{\vskip \cftbeforechapterskip}
}
\patchcmd\l@chapapp{%
  \vskip \cftbeforechapterskip
}{%
  \m@patch@toc@padding@top
}{}{}

\renewcommand*\afterchaptertitle{%
    \vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip \afterchapskip
}
\setlength\afterchapskip{12\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
(intentionally left blank)
\newpage
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Lorem}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Num dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output1]

---

[image: output2]